# Вопрос про Коллизию/Триггеры в Unity;

Tags: unity3d

Ломаю голову целый день , но не могу решить данную задачу. Вопрос следующий :Для начала,все шары имеют имя своего цвета то есть, красные шары с обеих сторон имеют имя red , черные black и тд. Слева шары  у них один родитель. Напротив шары расположены по х и у одинаково , только по оси z разные значения. В общем эти шары слева , точнее их родитель двигается по оси z к шарам справа, нужно проверить каждый шар при столкновении , с таким же цветом столкнулся объект или нет, если да то Destroy. Я надеюсь смог объяснить.  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно плохо понял вопрос, но можно все это решить с помощью методов OnCollisionEnter.
Они принимают переменную типа Collision или как-то так, можете глянуть все в интернете. Проверяйте цвет другого обьекта с вашим обьектом. Если цвет первого обьекта = цвету второго обьекта, Destroy(); Что тут сложного, не пойму.

Comment: JediMan, нужно одновременно проверить все четыре шара, если у всех true то удаляем родитель, соответственно удаляются шары слева. Я не могу придумать как это написать в коде. Хотя бы идею  без кода, помогло тоже.

Comment: Все равно плохо понимаю вопрос. Можно на каждый шар повесит скрипт с методами OnCollisionEnter и сделать небольшой массив, который будет ровнятся true, если все элементы в нем true.

Comment: насколько я понимаю если один шар столкнется с противоположным то значит что и все столкнулись. Ведь они не отличаются параметрами. По сути нужно проверить только для какого то одного .

Comment: JediMan правильно понял вопрос и правильно ответил на него. Для каждого отдельного шара будет свой ивент столкновения. Если с этого ивента вытащить колижнОбджект и посмотреть в свойствах цвет -- все получится. JediMan, ты молодец) Так держать и дальше в ответах)